# Enable download button when Quiz pass

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have these models in my Django Quiz app

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    quiz_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    num_questions = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    subject=models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.quiz_title


class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    question_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

I want when user pass Quiz then download certificate enable else disable I have different no. of Quizes in Different subjects...The main Idea is that I have courses and within courses I have sections And every sections of Course has Quizes so Every course has diffferent no. of sections and Quizes I want when user passes all the included Quiz in the sections like if first section has 3 quizes then if user pass all 3 quizes then certificate enable for download else disable...I have created logic for Quiz attempt and Result as well just problem is how can I get if student pass all the quizes that are included in the sections..Thanks Here is Quiz attempt and result views/logic

def single_quiz(request, quiz_id):
quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=quiz_id)
num_questions = len(quiz.question_set.all())

```
# deletes quiz and returns to home if no questions created
if num_questions == 0:
    quiz.delete()
    all_quiz_list = Quiz.objects.all()
    context = {
        'all_quiz_list': all_quiz_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'quiz/index.html', context)

quiz.num_questions = num_questions
quiz.save()

# resets accuracy info to 0
request.session["num_correct"] = 0
request.session["num_wrong"] = 0

context = {
    'quiz': quiz,
    'num_questions': num_questions,
}

return render(request, 'quiz/single_quiz.html', context)
```

## specific question view

def single_question(request, quiz_id, question_id):
quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=quiz_id)
current_question = quiz.question_set.get(question_num=question_id)

```
# Checks if currently on last question of quiz
next_or_submit = "Next"
last_question_check = False
if question_id == (len(quiz.question_set.all())):
    last_question_check = True
    next_or_submit = "Submit"

next_question_id = question_id+1

all_choices = current_question.choice_set.all()

context = {
    'current_question': current_question,
    'all_choices': all_choices,
    'quiz': quiz,
    'next_question_id': next_question_id,
    'last_question_check': last_question_check,
    'next_or_submit': next_or_submit
}

return render(request, 'quiz/single_question.html', context)
```

## view that receives info from user's answer to question and determines correctness

def vote(request, quiz_id, question_id):
quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=quiz_id)
current_question = quiz.question_set.get(question_num=question_id)

```
# checks if current question is last one
next_or_submit = "Next"
if question_id == (len(quiz.question_set.all())):
    next_or_submit = "Submit"

try:
    selected_choice = current_question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    # Redisplay the question voting form
    return render(request, 'quiz/single_question.html', {
        'quiz': quiz,
        'current_question': current_question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        'next_or_submit': next_or_submit,
    })
else:

    # get which choice is the correct answer
    correct_answer = current_question.choice_set.get(correct=True)

    if selected_choice == correct_answer:
        print("You are right")
        request.session["num_correct"] += 1
    else:
        print("You are wrong")
        request.session["num_wrong"] += 1

    # checks if next page should be results or next question
    if question_id == (len(quiz.question_set.all())):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('quiz:results', args=(quiz.id,)))
    else :
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('quiz:single_question', args=(quiz.id, question_id+1,)))
```

## quiz results page

def results(request, quiz_id):
quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=quiz_id)

```
num_correct = request.session["num_correct"]
num_wrong = request.session["num_wrong"]

total_questions = num_correct+num_wrong

# formats accuracy as % with no decimal digits
accuracy = num_correct/(total_questions)

accuracy_over_75 = False
if accuracy >= .75:
    accuracy_over_75 = True

accuracy_formatted = "{:.0%}".format(accuracy)

context = {
    'num_correct': num_correct,
    'num_wrong': num_wrong,
    'accuracy_over_75': accuracy_over_75,
    'accuracy_formatted': accuracy_formatted,
    'total_questions': total_questions,
    'quiz': quiz,
}
return render(request, 'quiz/results.html', context)
```